# Move back files

Tags: bash, unity-dash, 15.10

Tried to find out what was wrong with Unity, then I did this:
`mv backup_local/ .local/share/applications/` instead of `mv backup_local/*.desktop .local/share/applications/`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is you just moved `backup_local/` directory into `.local/share/applications` . Just like I've done in this small demo here:

```
xieerqi:$ ls TESTDIR
testfile

xieerqi:$ mkdir bin/ANOTHERDIR                                                

xieerqi:$ touch bin/ANOTHERDIR/testfile2                                      

xieerqi:$ mv TESTDIR/ bin/ANOTHERDIR/                                         

xieerqi:$ ls bin/ANOTHERDIR
TESTDIR/  testfile2

xieerqi:$ ls bin/ANOTHERDIR/TESTDIR                                           
testfile
```

To undo that just run `mv .local/share/applications/backup_local/ backup_local/`

Same as

```
xieerqi:$ mv bin/ANOTHERDIR/TESTDIR  TESTDIR                                  

xieerqi:$ ls -ld TESTDIR
drwxrwxr-x 2 xieerqi xieerqi 4096 11月  5 00:14 TESTDIR/

xieerqi:$ ls -l TESTDIR/                                                      
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 11月  5 00:14 testfile

xieerqi:$
```

Comment: `mv .local/share/applications/backup_local/ backup_local/`. That's funny :D, forgot to just undo what I did. Thanks.

Comment: Happens to the best of us ^_^ Just happy to help and glad you didn't loose any data

Comment: If I rebooted my computer, would I be in trouble? Unity maybe?

Comment: Nope, you just moved around files, that's all. Unity or anything else wouldn't be in any danger